# PHP - Shorten Sentence in a String If a Certain Word in an Array is Found

Tags: php, string, cpu-word, words, short

I am working on a PHP script which gets a METAR report and clears it up.  I need to shorten the METAR by deleting everything that follows if certain words are used.

For example, I need to delete everything after BECMG including the space in front of TEMPO in the following string as it is not needed:

```
$metars = "2013/12/24 07:30 NZOH 240730Z 31011G21KT 280V340 5000 -SHRA FEW020 BKN048 19/14 Q1006 BECMG 20KM TEMPO 6000 RA BKN012 SPECI COR NZOH 240730Z 31011G21KT 280V340 5000 -SHRA FEW020 BKN048 19/14 Q1006 BECMG 20KM TEMPO 6000 RA BKN012";

$comments = array ("BECMG", "RMK", "TEMPO");

$metar = ???
```

I need $metar to be:

```
$metar = "2013/12/24 07:30 NZOH 240730Z 31011G21KT 280V340 5000 -SHRA FEW020 BKN048 19/14 Q1006";
```

There lies the problem.  I can't use length numbers as the length can change.  How can I delete everything after a certain word is found out of an array of words including the space in front of the word to shorten the string?

Also, $metars includes BECMG and TEMPO.  How can I avoid having $metar include BECMG if it is shortened after another word is found?  In other words, I want ot avoid this from happening:

```
$metar = "2013/12/24 07:30 NZOH 240730Z 31011G21KT 280V340 5000 -SHRA FEW020 BKN048 19/14 Q1006 BECMG 20KM";
```

I want it to be:

```
$metar = "2013/12/24 07:30 NZOH 240730Z 31011G21KT 280V340 5000 -SHRA FEW020 BKN048 19/14 Q1006";
```

Comment: A preg_replace() would help you here. Don't ask me for RegEx though as I'm clueless when it comes to that! Haha  http://php.net/preg_replace

Comment: `strpos` with `foreach` also good enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a `foreach` loop and string functions like `strpos` and `substr` to achieve what you need:

```
$metar = "2013/12/24 07:30 NZOH 240730Z 31011G21KT 280V340 5000 -SHRA FEW020 BKN048 19/14 Q1006 BECMG 20KM TEMPO 6000 RA BKN012 SPECI COR NZOH 240730Z 31011G21KT 280V340 5000 -SHRA FEW020 BKN048 19/14 Q1006 BECMG 20KM TEMPO 6000 RA BKN012";
$comments = array ("BECMG", "RMK", "TEMPO");
foreach($comments as $comment){
$pos = strpos($metar, " ".$comment);
if($pos !== false)
$metar = substr($metar, 0, $pos);
}
// Now $metar is "2013/12/24 07:30 NZOH 240730Z 31011G21KT 280V340 5000 -SHRA FEW020 BKN048 19/14 Q1006"
```

Comment: Warning: Wrong parameter count for strstr()

I am not sure what is causing that in the code.

Comment: I’ve modified my answer. You’re probably using a PHP version before 5.3.0 when [strstr](http://php.net/strstr) didn’t have the optional “before_needle” parameter. Nevertheless, [substr](http://php.net/substr) will be good enough for your purpose.